# Truncating a table referenced by a foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, truncate

We have two tables in a SQL Server 2005 database, A and B.There is a service which truncates table A every day.

Recently, a foreign key constraint was added to table B, referencing table A. As a result, it isn't possible truncating table A anymore, even if table B is empty. Is there any workaround to get the same result as truncating table A?

I've already tried the approach below but the identity wasn't reset.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (TABLENAME, RESEED, 0)
```

PS. before anyone points this as a duplicate, the different thing here is that I'm not allowed to drop constraints, nor creating any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't drop the constraint, you can't use TRUNCATE TABLE, so you have to use DELETE.

```
DELETE TABLEA
DBCC CHECKIDENT (TABLENAME, RESEED, 0)
```

Note: Disabling the FK will not work either

Comment: I guess the problem was doing DELETE FROM TABLEA instead of DELETE TABLEA. Lame error, thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know what I was doing wrong, then. Anyways, it works now.

Answer (score -3):

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). -- Disable foreign key checking. TRUNCATE TABLE `table_name`;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). -- Enable foreign key checking.# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Comment: Way old question, anyways it's related to SQL Server rather than MySQL.

Answer (score -4):

If you want to truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint

```
1-DISABLE related FK
2-TRUNCATE all related tables.
3-ENABLE the previously disabled FKs

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; -- Disable foreign key checking.
TRUNCATE TABLE Table1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; -- Enable foreign key checking.
```

Comment: This is MySQL solution, while question pertains to MS Sql Server 2005